# std::list sentinel node from standard point of view

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, language-lawyer

Code example:

```cpp
    list<int> mylist{10, 20, 30, 40};
    auto p = mylist.end();
    while (true)
    {
        p++;
        if (p == mylist.end()) // skip sentinel
            continue;
        cout << *p << endl;
    }
```

I wonder, how much this code is legal from standard (C++17, n4810) point of view?
I looking for bidirectional iterators requirements related to example above, but no luck.

My question is:

Ability to pass through end(), it is implementation details or it is standard requirements?

Comment: The library never assumes that past-the-end values are dereferenceable. I think this applies not just to the `end ` but what comes after that as well.

Comment: You should use `++p` instead of `p++` anyway. Pre-increment has proper usage; yours isn't one of them.

Comment: Does your compiler (which one?) have some debug mode (checked iterators, sanitizer, etc)? Enabling it would answer this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the latest draft available online. 
[**`[iterator.requirements.general]/7`**](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements.general#7)

> Just as a regular pointer to an array guarantees that there is a pointer value pointing past the last element of the array, so for any iterator type there is an iterator value that points past the last element of a corresponding sequence. These values are called past-the-end values. Values of an iterator `i` for which the expression `*i` is defined are called dereferenceable. **The library never assumes that past-the-end values are dereferenceable.**

I believe that this applies not just to the `end()` but what comes after that as well. Note that the standard does not clearly state that `end()` should never be dereferenced.

And [**`Cpp17Iterator requirements table`**](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.iterators#tab:iterator.requirements) states that for expression `*r`, `r` should be dereferenceable:

[image]

past-the-end iterator is considered a non-incrementable iterator and incrementing it (as you are doing at the beginning of the `while` loop) results in undefined behavior.

Something like what you are trying to do can also happen when using [**`std::advance`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance).

The book ["The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference"](https://www.amazon.in/Standard-Library-Tutorial-Reference-2e/dp/8131791459) by Nicolai Josuttis has this quote:

> Note that `advance()` does not check whether it crosses the `end()` of a sequence (it can't check because iterators in general do not know the containers on which they operate). ***Thus, calling this function might result in undefined behavior because calling operator `++` for the end of a sequence is not defined.***

Answer (score 2):

You code is illegal. You first initialized `p` to be the *past-the-end iterator*.

```
auto p = mylist.end();
```

Now you `p++`. Per [Table 76](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements#tab:iterator.forward.requirements),
the operational semantics of `r++` is:

> ```
> { X tmp = r;
> ++r;
> return tmp; }
> ```

And per [[Table 74]](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements#tab:iterator.input.requirements),
`++r`

> *Expects:* `r` is dereferenceable.

And per [[iterator.requirements.general]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements#general-7),

> The library never assumes that past-the-end values are
>   dereferenceable.

In other words, incrementing a past-the-end iterator as you did is undefined behavior.